# Search and Compare using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have 2 files in below format :--

```
File 1.txt
id : 12
name : abc
value : 10
date : 11/20/2017
Mon : Nov

File 2.txt
name                 : abc
id                   : 123 
date                 : 11/20/2017
value                : 10
Year                 : 2017
```

I want output like

```
File Mismatch :id mismatch , File 1 Year missing , File 2 Mon Missing
```

I tried using diff but that will do only row by row match and if it is in same order it will say it matched or it will display difference.

Regards,

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: I tried using diff but that is not working . Now I am totally clueless what to compare.

Comment: won't give the exact format you need, but you can sort both files and use `diff -b` option to ignore space differences.. to get exact output, you need to write your own program, say with awk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a verbose `diff` output (for the 1st phase):

```
diff -b <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt)
```

The output:

```
2,3c2
< id : 12
< Mon : Nov
---
> id                   : 123 
5a5
> Year                 : 2017
```

---

- `< id : 12` and `< Mon : Nov` are lines unique to file `1.txt`
- `> id : 123` and `> Year : 2017` are lines unique to file `2.txt`

Comment: Thank you. I think I was missing sort part